# PS3 wont turn on

Tags: ps3, hardware

My ps3 super slim stopped working suddenly. It was working fine with no issues, but one day it just refused to turn on . Not even the red LED glows now. I tested the PSU following this video [Ps3 Super slim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIle6aH5FTA) .I confirm PSU is working well . So I am not sure what has gone wrong. Any help is appreciated. Following are the things I tried till now:

1.Replaced the Power/Eject ribbon with new one.

2.Opened the PS3 super slim to check if any thing burnt out, Everything looks fine.

3.Tested the PSU and it is working fine , the out put voltages are perfect as per the video mentioned above in the description.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29431/discussion-on-question-by-jaycyborg-ps3-wont-turn-on).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the power supply and make sure it is actually plugged in instead of loose. It is possible that it was in the middle of a software update where it is rewriting the system with the updated code so try and remember if there had been any power outages around the time it stopped working. I would just contact PS3 support and take it from there. You may be able to get it replaced or fixed for free if the warranty is still valid. I hope this helps!

Comment: Power supply is good , I even tested the output of the power supply with multimeter . The output voltages matches the voltage specified  by Sony .